# How to get the position of a Midi Note?

Tags: java, midi

I want to generate chords from a midi file, but I can't find any source code written in java yet.  So I want to write it by myself.  What I want to do first is to gather the notes in the same position, but this is the problem, I don't know if there is a way to get the midi note position using JMusic.  If not, are there any way to get this information?  Thank you all~

Comment: By "position" do you mean "place and duration in a measure(s)"? It's not quite that simple; MIDI files consist of note on/note off events (among other things). So a "chord" may not even be *n* "simultaneous" note-on/-off events, e.g., a note could go on, time passes, two other notes come on--is that a chord?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your answer.  I haven't thought about this complicatedly, so duration is not yet in consideration.  I just want to get the start position of the note firstly.

Comment: "I haven't thought about this complicatedly" - you're supposed to do some basic independent research before asking SO.

Comment: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92092/ref/midi/ -  midi files contain events, each of which has a number representing the time since the previous event.

Answer (score -1):

Like slim mentioned, Midi files are basically a collection of Midi Events, which are basically hex bytes of code that correspond to a Midi action. EVERYTHING in Midi (including very in-depth things like tempo, setting the instrument bank to typical things such as note on/off events and note volume [called velocity in MIDI]) is controlled by those Midi Events. Unfortunately, you're going to need ALL of that information in order to do what you want.

My advice? There is this odd notion (that I once held before working with Midi as well) that Midi should be simple to work with because it's been around for so long and it's so easy to use in DAW's like FL Studio. Well let me be the person to crush this notion for you; MIDI is complex, hard, and idiosyncratic. As a beginner, it will force you to take caffeine (to keep the gears rolling and for headaches), tylenol (also for the headaches) and alcohol when you realize you just worked 6 hours for one thing and you're getting the fatigue. Turn back now, pay Dave Smith to help you, or hit the books, cause it's going to get nasty.

HOWEVER: You will never feel greater success than when your baby starts playing music.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  Since I haven't deal with the raw data of midi, cuz I've been using JMusic to get the midi information, so I might underestimate the difficulty of generating midi file info.  I am writing an android application which needs information from midi files, that's the reason why I need to deal with the midi information rather than using other software to do so.  Thanks again for spending your time on my question.